# Validating credit card number using regular expression

Tags: regex, credit-card

Credit Card Number format is : "nnnn nnnn nnnn nnnn"

I tested four strings below with this pattern, but the temp3 string unexpectedly returns true.

I don't know what's wrong. The regular expression I'm using should validate for four digits and one space exactly, but temp3 returns true despite not matching this pattern.

```
String temp1 = " adfs 1111 2222 3333 4444 fadad";  // outer test
String temp2 = "11 11 2222 3333 4444"; // inner test
String temp3 = "11111 2222 3333 4444"; // inner test
String temp4 = "1111 2a222 3333 4444"; // inner test

public String chkContainCardno(String inputstr) {

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]{4}\\s[0-9]{4}\\s[0-9]{4}\\s[0-9]{4}");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(inputstr);

    if (m.find()) {
        return m.group(0);
    } else {
        return ErrMsg.Does_Not_Contain_Card_No;
    }
}
```

[Test Result]

temp1 : `adfs 1111 2222 3333 4444 fadad` : true `1111 2222 3333 4444`

temp2 : `11 11 2222 3333 4444` : false

temp3 : `11111 2222 3333 4444` : true `1111 2222 3333 4444` <-- **I don't understand**

temp4 : `1111 2a222 3333 4444` : false

Comment: 1st and 3rd are the only input which matched the pattern to find 4 groups of 4 digit numbers

Comment: There is a actual algorithm to check if a credit card is a real credit card number or not, it is called the [Luhn algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm)

Answer (score 3):

The third test passes because you have no anchors around your pattern. You should add `\b` at either end i.e. `"\\b[0-9]{4}\\s[0-9]{4}\\s[0-9]{4}\\s[0-9]{4}\\b"` to force the match within word boundaries.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/michaelkeevildown/9096cd3aac9029c4e6e05588448a8841

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
"(\\b\\d{4}\\s\\d{4}\\s\\d{4}\\s\\d{4}\\b)"
```

b - word boundaries

d - digit